# Auto Increment starts from one

Tags: javascript

I Have Modal Form Which opens When someone clicks Add Query (**Button on Page** )  Popup Form Opens and  Given javascript create a number From 1 in Reference No in input field...

My Javascript

```
<script>                                                                    
var seq = 0;function myFunction() {                                          
if (localStorage.getItem("seq")) {
seq = +localStorage.getItem("seq") + 1;                                       
} else {                                            
localStorage.setItem("seq", 2217);
seq = 1;  }                       
document.getElementById("reference_no").value = seq;}  </script>
```

**Button on Page**

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="myFunction()"                     
  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" Value="Add Query"></button
```

**When Pop Modal Open**

```
<input id="reference_no"  autocomplete="off" name="reference_no" placeholder="" type="text"  
  class="form-control"  value="" />                                                                 
  <button name="save" value="save" onclick="saveEnquiry()" class="btn btn-info pull-right"></button>
```

Save Enquiry Java Script

```
function saveEnquiry() {


    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/enquiry/add/',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $("#formadd").serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == "fail") {

                var message = "";
                $.each(data.error, function (index, value) {

                    message += value;
                });
                errorMsg(message);
            } else {

                successMsg(data.message);
                window.location.reload(true);
            }

        },



        error: function () {
            alert("Fail")
        }
    });


}
```

**Here Onclick function save the form to the database**

But the problem is When I save the modal Form and Then Click Again the Add Query Button the number starts from 1 But I am Looking For it Starts from 2 and after submitting the form it starts with 3 and so on

I Hope You understand the issue...

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `localStorage` to persist the `seq` number.

```
var seq = 0;
function myFunction() {
  if (localStorage.getItem("seq")) {
    seq = +localStorage.getItem("seq") + 1;
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("seq", 2217);
    seq = 2217;
  }
  document.getElementById("reference_no").value = seq;
}

function saveEnquiry() {

 let seq = document.getElementById("reference_no").value;
 if(seq) {
     localStorage.setItem("seq", seq);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sohail, What if i want to start numbers from 1000 not from 1 as i tried but its not working

Comment: i changed  localStorage.setItem("seq", 1); to localStorage.setItem("seq", 2217); when  the form saved it started from 2

Comment: lets say i want to start serial numbers from 2217 not from 1

Comment: how can i start the numbers from 2217..same as changing the localStorage.setItem("seq", 1); to localStorage.setItem("seq", 2217) with updated code

Comment: Try this link. Live example : https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-burnell-bz3bb

Comment: i cleared the chached memory and its working fine....but let me know if i cleared my chached memory then it will again start with 2217 or it will start from the last value

Comment: Yes. I will again start from initial value. if you to avoid this then you have to add this in some backend database.

Comment: the values are saving in db in refrence no field also now if form closes accedently the giving me a new value how can i avoid this too

Comment: Save the `localStorage.setItem` value in `saveEnquiry` this will solve the `closes accedently` issue.

Comment: function saveEnquiry() { localStorage.setItem("seq", 2217);
    seq = 2217; } like this

Comment: save enquiry javascript added

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getRid () {
    'use strict';
    var i = 1000;
    getRid = function () {
        return i++;
    };
    return i++;
}
console.log(getRid ());
console.log(getRid ());
console.log(getRid ());
console.log(getRid ());
```

---

use localstorage

```js
function getId(){
   const id = localStorage.getItem('_id') || 1000;
    localStorage.setItem('_id', Number(id)+1);
     return id.toString()
}

console.log(getId());
console.log(getId());
console.log(getId());
```

Comment: If your page is refreshed, you can use localstorage sessionstorage

Comment: can you please let me know how to use local storage from this

Comment: let me check and let you know

Comment: function not showing data in input field <input id="reference_no"  autocomplete="off" name="reference_no" placeholder="" type="text"  
  class="form-control"  value="" />   i changed _id to   reference_no